# ItemTemplate ListBox выходит за пределы размера формы

Tags: wpf

Вот код ListBox

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="NewsListBox" Padding="5">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid RowSpan="0" Width="Auto" Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" MaxWidth="256"></Image>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Cursor="Hand" Text="{Binding Path=NewsTitle}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NewsText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=NewsListBox, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Вот что получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

TextBlock выходит за пределы формы и появляется прокрутка. Если не привязывать ширину то весь текст идет одной строкой. Собственно вопрос, как написать правильно что бы не появлялась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки, то-есть контейнер растягивался только до границ окна.

Comment: А что такое `dxe`?

Comment: Это компонент DevExpress, я ставил и стандартный ListBox вместо ListBoxEdit, та же проблема. Менял по разному настройки, оставлял только один TextBlock, ничего не меняется.

Comment: Если вы опубликуете пример без `dxe`, вам смогут помочь и те, у кого DevExpress нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня работает так:

```
<!-- имя не нужно, добавил HorizontalContentAlignment и
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility -->
<ListBox Padding="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- RowSpan не нужно, Width не нужно -->
            <Grid Margin="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <!-- добавил TextWrapping -->
                    <TextBlock Cursor="Hand" Text="..." FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="..."
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Адаптируйте!

---

<sup>Украдено (и уже не первый раз) с благодарностью из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12096448/276994).</sup>

Comment: Да все верно. В моем случае достаточно было добавить ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" и соответственно убрать привязку в TextBlock к ширине.

Спасибо!

Comment: @jurzer: Пожалуйста!