# Как сделать перенос строк в гриде Avalonia?

Tags: c#, xaml, avalonia

Хочу сделать список, у которого есть 3 столбца (можно не гридом, не знаю как иначе), где второй столбец это длинная строка, занимающая оставшееся пространство, размер которой я заранее не знаю. Добавил TextWrapping="Wrap", но это не работает. Как сделать?

```
<ListBox Items="{Binding Items}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="4" Padding="4">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Image</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Classes="address" Text="{Binding DisplayTime^}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding DisplayTitle^}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding DisplayAddress^}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button VerticalAlignment="Center">Ведущий</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: `но это не работает` - и тут мы должны включить режим ванги? Ок, предположу, что появляется полоса прокрутки, ибо элемент уходит за пределы области видимости, значит, что надо сделать? Правильно, отключить его `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` или как там в вашей авалонии это делается... А еще скорей всего, вас интересует вопрос "как растянуть на все окно?" - `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: Про авалонию лучше на английском SO спрашивать с тегом `avaloniaui`, там даже сами разработчики могут ответить. А так, ваш вопрос непонятен, совсем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, вы правы, там появляется скролл, который я честно говоря не видел до текущего момента.

Comment: Можете написать ответ, отмечу как правильное решение. Спасибо.

Comment: На SO есть уже подобные вопросы и ответы на них, например [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850431/220553) или [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/493500/220553), увы, но искать тут мало кто желает, верно?)